# Craft 3.5.1 CLI Update Error: Failed to instantiate component or class "yii\shell\Bootstrap"

Tags: craft3, updates

when I try to update Craft via CLI to 3.5.1. I get the following error:

```
Failed to instantiate component or class "yii\shell\Bootstrap
in /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:449

Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(374): yii\di\Container->getDependencies()
#1 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(159): yii\di\Container->build()
#2 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(345): yii\di\Container->get()
#3 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(294): yii\BaseYii::createObject()
#4 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(72): yii\base\Application->bootstrap()
#5 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(273): craft\console\Application->bootstrap()
#6 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(124): yii\base\Application->init()
#7 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(58): yii\console\Application->init()
#8 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\console\Application->init()
#9 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(206): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct()
#10 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(89): yii\base\Application->__construct()
#11 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(48): yii\console\Application->__construct()
#12 [internal function]: craft\console\Application->__construct()
#13 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(400): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs()
#14 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(159): yii\di\Container->build()
#15 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get()
#16 /vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php(245): yii\BaseYii::createObject()
#17 /vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/console.php(51): require('/var/www/client...')
#18 /craft(21): require('/var/www/client...')
#19 {main}
```

does anyone know what to do about it?

Comment: Try to remove/rename your `vendor` folder then run `composer clearcache` then `composer install`

Comment: @Oli This got me out of a jam. Thanks!

Comment: @Oli 's suggestion helped me when I had a similar error updating via CLI to 3.7.40.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up being a bug we were able to work-around on our side via our web service calls.

If you restore your site from a pre-update attempt database backup and composer.json file, then attempt the update again, it should go through fine.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue today with a fairly old project and was able to fix it by rolling back to Composer 1 locally (`composer self-update --1`), then updating all of the dependencies and reinstalling, then switching back to Composer 2 (`composer self-update --2`) and running `composer install` a second time to pick up on any C2-specific changes.